Обращение к определённой переменной в определённой структуре в динамически выделенной памяти
Есть структура, которая указывается в качестве типа при создании динамически выделенной памяти malloc().
Как обращаться к определённой переменной в структуре, находящейся
по определённому номеру в динамически выделенной памяти?
Так:
printf("%d",structName[N].X)

Или как?

В общем так, но нужно показать код объявления типа и код выделения памяти

_________зачем?

Чтобы убедиться, что мы правильно поняли ваше словесное описание.
